# Align Input file on Bootstrap input text

Tags: css

i have tried designing my own input file base on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Snippet/YBWq3/1/) i need to align properly the button in input text of a bootstrap.

this is my code to design my input type. also the button of bootstrap is not aligning.

```
.forUplBtn {
    background-color:#427db8; 
    width:50px;

    display:inline-block;
    border: none;
    color: #fff; 
    padding:5px 20px 5px 20px;
    border:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
}
.forUplBtn a{
    z-index:-1;
}



.forUplBtn input[type="file"]{
    /*margin-left:-145px;*/
    width: 100%;height:100%; position:absolute; left:0;top:0; opacity:0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `vertical-align:top` to `.forUplBtn` and add this for the upload button:

```
.uplPhot a button{
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below `css` to your code

```
button {
     position: absolute;
     margin-left: -90px;
     width: 90px;
     margin-top:4px
 }
```

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YBWq3/2/)

Also check [**Jasny's fork Bootstrap**](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload) for file upload, easy to integrate.

Comment: there is a space on top and left of the upload button..but thanks for the link